# Python: (Beautifulsoup) How to limit extracted text from a html news article to only the news article.

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I wrote this test code which uses BeautifulSoup.

```
url = "http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3795511/Harry-Potter-sale-half-million-pound-house-Iconic-Privet-Drive-market-suburban-Berkshire-complete-cupboard-stairs-one-magical-boy.html"    
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()  
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
for n in soup.find_all('p'):
    print(n.get_text())
```

It works fine but it also retrieves text that is not part of the news article, such as the time it was posted, number of comments, copyrights ect.

I would wish for it to only retrieve text from the news article itself, how would one go about this?

Comment: You have to look at the website and how is it made. Is the news in a certain class or a certain tag? Then you can filter using BS4 based on the tag and class or id.

Comment: For this article, filter for this: <div itemprop="articleBody">. This won't necessarily hold for other sites or sometimes even articles on the same site, so you need to look at the HTML for each.

Answer (score 2):

You might have much better luck with [`newspaper` library](http://newspaper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which is focused on scraping articles.

If we talk about `BeautifulSoup` only, one option to get closer to the desired result and have more relevant paragraphs is to find them in the context of `div` element with `itemprop="articleBody"` attribute:

```
article_body = soup.find(itemprop="articleBody")
for p in article_body.find_all("p"):
    print(p.get_text())
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to target more specifically than just the `p` tag. Try looking for a `div class="article"` or something similar, then only grab paragraphs from there

Answer (score 1):

Be more specific, you need to catch the `div` with `class` `articleBody`, so :

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3795511/Harry-Potter-sale-half-million-pound-house-Iconic-Privet-Drive-market-suburban-Berkshire-complete-cupboard-stairs-one-magical-boy.html"    
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()  
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
for n in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'itemprop':"articleBody"}):
    print(n.get_text())
```

Responses on SO is not just for you, but also for people coming from google searches and such. So as you can see, `attrs` is a dict, it is then possible to pass more attributes/values if needed.

Comment: your approach doesn't work for url='https://newsbeezer.com/brazil/brasil-pode-perder-certificado-de-eliminao-do-sarampo-nacional/'. A more general approach would be to look for <div> which has property "articleBody" and then look for div and p tags